# The number of continuous real-valued functions on $[-1,1]$ such that $(f(x))^2=x^2$ for all $x$ in the domain

Tags: real-analysis

I've been thinking about the following problem:

How many continuous real-valued functions $f$ are there with domain $[-1,1]$ such that $(f(x))^2=x^2$ for each $x$ in $[-1,1]$?

> I thought that there are two continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[-1,1]$ such that $(f(x))^2=x^2$, but why should there be four such functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is that $f(x)=\pm |x|$.  Hence $x, -x, |x|, -|x|$ all fit the bill.

Comment: Thank you vadim123! I was starting at the screen when functions involving the absolute value suddenly came to mind.